# Subset Dataframe for specific column value in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have the following dataset:
[image]

I am trying to find which country reported the most hotels with a name beginning with A from 1 January 2022 to 1 Jan 2022.

I tried creating a subset of the data for the time period first:

```
new1 = (ad['date'] > '2020-1-1') & (ad['date'] <= '2022-1-1')

print(ad.loc[new1])
```

But I am slightly confused on how to add the other columns to the subset. And add the other condition of where the hotel name begins with A.

Comment: Can you post your code including the dataframe as [example], so we can reproduce? We don't have your Excel or CSV file. Please also research here in stackoverflow for [tag:pandas] questions related to filtering.

Comment: unfortunately I can't add the dataframe code